# My code always creates a csv. If one or more of the 24 textboxes are null it shouldn't create csv file

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

My form has 24 textboxes and when you press button it creates a csv file with that 24 input. If one or more of them are null, it should not create a csv file but it always creates csv file when I press the button. Also in control foreach loop, both if and else if conditions work, I couldn't understand that. Can you please help me ?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh/mm");
            string tarih = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            string saat = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("hh/mm");
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path + "\\" + theDate + ".csv");
            // Create an instance of the StreamWriter class

            try
            {
                // Loop through all the text boxes in the form
                foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (control is TextBox)
                    {
                        if (control.Text == "" || control.Text == null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Lütfen Boş Alanlara Bir Değer Giriniz!");
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
                        {
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            sb.AppendLine("Değerler, Tarih, Saat");
                            // Get the text from the TextBox
                            string text = ((TextBox)control).Text;
                            // Create an array from the text by splitting it
                            // on line breaks
                            string[] lines = text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" },
                            StringSplitOptions.None);
                            // Write each line to the file
                            foreach (string line in lines)
                            {
                                if (control.Text != "" && control.Text != null)
                                {
                                    writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", tarih, saat, Convert.ToDouble(line) * 10));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Lütfen Sayı Giriniz");
            }

            // Close the file
            writer.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean the `if` and `else` both work? If you want to validate all of the controls before writing the file then you need to split your logic up to do that. Right now you always open the file before you check anything.

Comment: think carefully about what you want to do ... what happens in your program if only the last text control is blank

Comment: Why don't you make a function to recursively check the inputs and return a boolean ? Something like `if (inputboxes_are_ok) { actions() } else { error_handling() }`

Answer (score 3):

Your post states:

> If one or more of them are null, it should not create a csv file.

This suggests that you would want to use a Linq statement to check for `Any` textbox that is empty, and only enter the loop if this condition is `false`. Here's one way this could be coded:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh/mm");
    string tarih = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    string saat = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("hh/mm");
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

    try
    {
        // Check 'before' entering the csv writer block. If
        // any textbox has an empty value, do not enter the loop.
        TextBox[] textboxes = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();
        if (!textboxes.Any(_=> string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_.Text)))
        {
            // Create an automatic dispose of StreamWriter class instance
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path + "\\" + theDate + ".csv"))
            {
                // Loop through all the text boxes in the form. Additional
                // checks for null or empty are 'not' required here
                // because all were checked before entering the loop. 
                foreach (var textbox in textboxes)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.AppendLine("Değerler, Tarih, Saat");
                    // Get the text from the TextBox
                    string text = textbox.Text;
                    // Create an array from the text by splitting it on line breaks
                    string[] lines = text.Split(
                        new [] { "\r\n", "\n" },
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    // Write each line to the file
                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        if(double.TryParse(line, out double value))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine($"{tarih},{saat},{value * 10}");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show($"The line '{line}' could not be converted to double.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Lütfen Sayı Giriniz");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because have the extra {} at the end of the line.

```
else if (control.Text != "" && control.Text != null) { } // here
{
 // so this block always go
}
```

And I think this null check is better

```
// old
if(control.Text != "" && control.Text != null)
// new
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
```

Comment: I looked at it a couple of times and didn't spot the extra `{}`. Good eyes!

Comment: I deleted extra {} and changed it like if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text)) but still it creates an empty csv. I tried everything but it is still creating.

Comment: @IVSoftware 's answer is good!